# Trivial cohomology for fibers implies isomorphism on cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $f: Y \rightarrow X$ be a map of topological spaces such that for any $x \in X, f^{-1}(x)$ has trivial cohomology for some cohomology theory (in my case, cohomology with rational coefficients is enough). Is it true that $f$ induces an isomorphism on cohomology for the same theory?

If not, does this become true if we assume $f$ is a map of CW-complexes, or in some similar way nice?

edited to add some context: I'm hoping for a similar result to [Homotopy equvalence from contractibility of fiber.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126425/homotopy-equvalence-from-contractibility-of-fiber); however, I'm hoping to replace weak homotopy equivalence with some cohomology theory, both in the assumption and the conclusion.

Comment: With no hypotheses on $X, Y$ there are silly counterexamples like $Y$ the circle with the usual topology and $X$ the circle with the indiscrete topology. Even aside from that sort of thing, if $f$ isn't a fibration there's no reason a priori to expect its genuine fibers to have much to do with its homotopy theory. In the positive direction, if $f$ is a fibration and $X$ is simply connected then I think the Serre spectral sequence does it.

Comment: I don't have much background in algebraic topology, so I may be asking a stupid question here: it doesn't seem as if $f$ being a fibration is used in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126425/homotopy-equvalence-from-contractibility-of-fiber, so is it fully necessary?

Comment: Yes, that theorem is quite surprising to me; I have no idea how it's proved. ("No reason a priori to expect X" doesn't mean "X is false"; it means what it says.) There's a similar result for cohomology here (but its hypotheses are pretty strong): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietoris%E2%80%93Begle_mapping_theorem

Comment: That does seem like it answers the question - the case I'm looking at has X and Y as compact affine real varieties, and so compact metric spaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: If $f$ is a fibration, we don't have to go as far as the Serre spectral sequence, just to Leray-Hirsch. (The class $1$ already restricts to a basis of cohomology of each fiber.)